# How to execute shell script with sudo from java backend?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I can't figure out how to execute a command like sudo some.sh from a java backend. The sudo is pwdless.

I tried with  exec() and with builder without any luck (see below). If i try passing exec("sudo touch text.txt"); it works.

```
 String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "/var/backup/dump/replication.sh"};
        Process procScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript);
```

Any ideas what i may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I would try becoming the user your Java application runs as, then execute `sudo touch text.txt`. Wrong `sudoers` entries and different working directories (try absolute paths) are the most common pitfalls here I can think of.

Comment: Add `set -x; exec > /tmp/logfile 2>&1` as the second line in the script and then check out the trace logs and error messages in `/tmp/logfile`

Comment: tried all options. I'm passing absolute paths and also my sudo user doesn't require password. also tried to put the script in /tmp and execute from there, nothing works. logfile gets nothing filled in as well.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be:

```
String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "sudo /var/backup/dump/replication.sh"};
```

or

```
String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "sudo", "/var/backup/dump/replication.sh"};
```

Since sudo usually requires a password, you might need to pipe a password into it.

```
String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash -c", "echo 'password' | sudo -S /var/backup/dump/replication.sh"};
```

This is not tested, but should get you on the right track.  If not, it looks like it was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476924/sudo-in-java-process/19936128#19936128).

Comment: I added a reference for you to check out